# Entity Framework Interceptor adding entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, interception

I am using EF 6 and attempting to use the IDbCommandInterceptor from the System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception namespace.

It works well for reading, and updating, however when I add a new entity to the database, the NonQueryExecuted() does not fire, nor does the NonQueryExecuting().  Is this normal behavior by the Interceptor or is something not being implemented correctly on my end?

Code:

Interceptor:

```
    public void NonQueryExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
        {
            this.MonitorAndNotifySignalRService(command);
        }

public void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
    }

    public void ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
        {
        }

        public void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
        {
        }

    public void ScalarExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
        {
        }

    public void ScalarExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
        {
        }
```

DataContextBase:

```
        static Constructor()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<TDataContext>(null);        // turn off database initialization so the db schema is not changed from the model
        DbInterception.Add(new Interceptor());
    }
```

Comment: I would say that inserting a new entity means that the engine reads back the assigned identity.

Comment: @WiktorZychla, Can you elaborate on that? What do you mean by the engine reading back the assigned identity? This should be fired before the command is sent to the SQL server, and that happens for Updates and Reads, but not for Inserts.

Comment: What Wiktor means is that an insert query is paired with a read command to read a generated identity value or computed columns back to the application. So it's the `ReaderExecuted/ing` that gets fired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design. When an entity with a database-generated identity is inserted, an insert statement is accompanied by a `SELECT` statement to read the generated identity value into the Id property of the inserted entity. The command has this shape:

```sql
INSERT [dbo].[Table](...)
VALUES (...)
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[Table]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()
```

It triggers the `ReaderExecuting/ReaderExecuted` pair.

If, on the other hand, an entity hasn't got a database-generated identity, the entity can just be inserted without a subsequent `SELECT` statement. In this case the `NonQueryExecuting/NonQueryExecuted` pair is triggered. (As I tested myself).